# Is there any way to dynamically set the icon of view/part in eclipse rcp?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to change the image of view/part in eclipse rcp with my application theme .As of now this is not E4 application so we are still using org.eclipse.ui.views as extension point.So I had hardcode the image path in icon path of extension .

I think this can be done if I can set the icon from the code .Is there way to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class extending `ViewPart` can change the image by calling the `setTitleImage` method:

```java
protected void setTitleImage(Image titleImage)
```

Comment: Yes I tried setting using this anyways Thanks for answer